# What do Amadeus GDS itinerary header codes mean?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, gds

I have few questions on Amadeus itinerary header lines

```
--- TST RLR MSC RLP ---                                                         
RP/BOMVS1234/BOMVS1234            HZ/SU   7NOV12/1027Z   11WW22                 
BOMVS1234/0007HZ/8AUG12
```

another example

```
--- RLR TC-PER MSC RLP ---                                                      


RP/BOMVS1234/BOMVS1234            AF/RM   3SEP13/1317Z   4XY5FS                 
BOMVS1234/0007HZ/3SEP13
```

1. What does the first line codes mean?

   - TST Transitional Stored Ticket (?)
   - RLR Record Locator Return (?)
   - MSC Married segment (?)
   - RLP (?)
   - TC-PER (?)

2) I understand 7NOV12/1027Z is the booking time. What does the letter Z signify after the time.

3) What does HZ/SU mean in line 2?

3) What does the date 8AUG12 signify to in line 3?

4) Is 0007HZ time? of what? And what does HZ mean?

Comment: Z in time presentation stands for GMT/UTC timezone (00:00 offset)

Comment: @MeNoTalk If anyone can answer this, I bet it's you. :)

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee I was too lazy to open the Amadeus reference and check it :) I forgot these codes since it is not my day to day thing..

Comment: @MeNoTalk Would be grateful if you could give me a reference at least or may be the link to the manual you refer to!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

HZ/SU means the last person to touch this PNR was agent HZ, who has a _SU_pervisor role. 0007HZ is the full signing for the agent, who works at BOMVS1234.

TC-PER means that all availability requests done while having this PNR open will be biased as per the policy established by the agency under the PER designator.

TST means there is a stored TST in the PNR, while RLR means that all or some of the airlines involved in this itinerary have returned an airline reference.

Comment: Can you answer what RLP and MSC are as well?

Comment: Yes: RLP, as was mentioned, means the PNR was created from a profile, while MSC means there is married segment information that can be retrieved with RTIM.

Comment: if you add those both to your answer it becomes a very complete answer, and one that should be acceptable to the OP. As it is you are only partially complete as an answer, and I recognize your knowledge and expertise as being able to finish it. :) Well done, by the way.

Comment: I am giving it to you because the HZ/SU code were real tough ones!! cheers!

Answer (score 6):

Some [codes](http://api.dev.amadeus.net/api/Development/common/codelist/PNRTagline.htm) are listed here.

RLR is indeed Record Locator Return, read more in this [guide](http://www.asc-me.net/upload/1ABasicCourseTrainingGuideVer2_1523.pdf).

An [Amadeus guide for profiles](http://www.amadeus.com/web/binaries/blobs/910/895/Amadeus%20Profiles%20Manual_v1,0.pdf) guide says:

> RLP-tag on the header line indicates that the PNR is created from a profile

BOMVS1234 is a Pseudo City Code (PCC) which is a fancy name for "agent code".

Edit: I found HZ/SU for you! That's [SAT Airlines](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SAT_Airlines) (now Aurora) codesharing with [Aeroflot](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aeroflot). And 0007HZ is surely the flight number.

Comment: Hey chx, gratitude! Any clue on 8aug12 on line 3?

Comment: Also why is code share mentioned here when each sector element in the itinerary has 010 for code shares?

Comment: I just checked there is no flight as HZ 0007

Comment: In 2012? It was a different airline then.

Comment: I have samples of these code which mentiones 'RM' as one of its codes and I dont believe in any point in time its the IATA code for any airlines