# How many travelers are there in the e-ticket? What's the itinerary?

Tags: air-travel, tickets, emirates

`——— RLR MSC——-
CKT2480/
SK 854 K 16JUN 6*KWIDXB DKI 0330 0620  16JUN E 0. 77W M
ADD PASSPORT DETAILS IN SSR DOCS AND CONTACT IN SSR CTCM
ADD NEXT OF KIN CONTACT IN SSR PCTC
SEE RTSVC
EK 333 K 29JUN 5*MNLDXB DK1 1815 2300  29JUN. E 0. 77w M
SEE RTSVC
EK 853 K 30JUN 6*DCBKWI DK1 0140. 30JUN E 0. 77w M
ADD PASSPORT DETAILS IN SSR DOCS AND CONTACT IN SSR CTCM
ADD NEXT OF THE KIN CONTACT IN SSR PCTC`

Comment: @HenningMakholm They're output from an airline GDS reservation system (see [here](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/45003/what-do-amadeus-gds-itinerary-header-codes-mean/120345#120345)). They show various Emirates flight numbers and origin/destination pairs. However, the booking reference and other details are missing, and they've all been mashed together on one line here. They're in all caps because that's how such systems work.

Comment: With quite a few typos along the way, I think.

Answer (score 3):

This looks like an Emirates reservation.

Go to [Emirates.com](https://www.emirates.com/us/english/). Click "Manage booking or check in."

Type in the last name of one of the travelers and the booking reference. If you don't know the booking reference, you need to ask whoever booked the ticket; it's probably in the same email that contains the text you've copy/pasted above.

You'll get a screen that displays all the information about your trip, including the origin, destination, flights, and the names of the travelers.